# Append suffix to Chart.js dataset?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

I'm using [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) to display data on my site, and would like to append a suffix to the data fields, to indicate that they are in grams (g). I can't find anything in the documentation that seems to help, but it seems like quite a simple feature.

For example, I'd like to ensure that data displays as 32g, 38g, 53g, rather than just 32, 38, 53. You can't simply add it into the array as this is required as numbers only to generate the chart.

**PHP**

```
$myChart = array(
    "type" => "doughnut",
    "data" => array(
        "labels" => ['Label1', 'Label2', 'Label3'],
        "datasets" => [
            array(
                "data" => [ 32, 38, 53 ],
            )
        ]
    )
);
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="chart" data-charts="{"type":"doughnut","data":{"labels":["Label1","Label2","Label3"],"datasets":[{"data":["56","31","21"],}]}}">
    <div class="chart-container">
        <canvas class="chartjs-render-monitor">
        </canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
// Chart init
window.onload = function() {

    // Find all charts
    var containers = document.querySelectorAll('.chart');

    // For each chart
    containers.forEach(function(container) {

        // Parse data
        var charts = JSON.parse(container.dataset.charts);

        // Add container div
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.classList.add('chart-container');

        // Add canvas for chart to be drawn in
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

        // Append new elements
        div.appendChild(canvas);
        container.appendChild(div);

        // Config
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var config = charts;

        // Init chart
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);

    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work you can use the callback of the tooltips configuration to append a string to the value in the dataset, something like this:

```js
var containers = document.querySelectorAll('.chart');
containers.forEach(function(container) {
  var charts = JSON.parse(container.dataset.charts);

  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList.add('chart-container');

  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  div.appendChild(canvas);
  container.appendChild(div);

  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var config = charts;
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, $.extend(config, {
    options: {
      tooltips: {
        enabled: true,
        mode: 'single',
        callbacks: {
          label: function(tooltipItems, data) {
            return data.datasets[0].data[tooltipItems.index] + 'g';
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }));
});
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart" data-charts='{"type":"doughnut","data":{"labels":["Label1","Label2","Label3"],"datasets":[{"data":["56","31","21"]}]}}'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Rory, this looks great! Only trouble I'm having is that my structure differs from yours slightly, and I'm getting JS errors in the final function. Is there any way you could reformat to match my structure please? The error seems to be within the function(tooltipItems, data) section?

Comment: It hard to fix the issue without being able to see it. I made a guess as to what your JS data structure looks like based on the PHP array you posted in the question. If you could edit the question to include the actual JS I may be able to edit the answer for you

Comment: Sure, sorry I should have included the full shebang initially. I've updated the question as requested. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, could you include the `.chart` div as it's rendered to the HTML. The PHP isn't relevant to the issue and is what's making the solution unclear.

Comment: There's a couple of issues. Firstly your double quotes are mismatched. You need to use `'` for the outer HTML attribute otherwise it would interfere with the `"` in the JSON. Secondly, you can't place a function within the JSON you put in to the `data` attribute as I originally suggested. To get around that you can use jQuery's `$.extend()` to add the tooltip configuration options to the chart data before you call the Chart.js constructor . I've updated the answer for you.

Comment: Hi Rory. Sorry for the delay in reply, I had a day off yesterday. This is perfect and I have marked as resolved, thank you very much for all the input. The only final niggling bug I can see is that I get a jQuery error on var myChart = new Chart(ctx, $.extend(config, { saying that 'Chart' is not defined. Can this be eradicated?

Comment: No problem, glad to help. You'd get that error if you haven't included the chart library in the page, or if you included it *after* you call `new Chart()`

Comment: Thanks. chart.js is included before my code above, do I also need to declare something in the script above?

Comment: No, that should work, as you can see from the example in my answer. I'd suggest opening a new question which shows all the HTML and the script includes.